# How to iterate over pairs of elements in table in lua

Tags: loops, lua, lua-table

How to iterate over pairs of table elements in lua? I would like to achieve a side-effect free way of circular and non-circular iterating ver pairs.

```
I have table like this:
t = {1,2,3,4}

Desired output of non-circular iteration:
(1,2)
(2,3)
(3,4)

Desired output of circular iteration:
(1,2)
(2,3)
(3,4)
(4,1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the circular case

```
for i = 1, #t do 
  local a,b
  a = t[i]
  if i == #t then b = t[1] else b = t[i+1] end 
  print(a,b) 
end
```

Non circular:

```
for i = 1, #t-1 do 
  print(t[i],t[i+1]) 
end
```

For fancier output use `print(string.format("(%d,%d)",x,y)`

Answer (score 6):

Another solution for the circular case

```
   local n=#t
    for i=1,n do 
      print(t[i],t[i%n+1]) 
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

How about having no special case for both cases?

```
function print_pair(x, y)
   local s = string.format("(%d, %d)", x, y)
   print(s)
end

function print_pairs(t)
   for i = 1, #t - 1 do
      print_pair(t[i], t[i + 1])
   end
end

function print_pairs_circular(t)
   print_pairs(t)
   print_pair(t[#t], t[1])
end
```